# Why does on click if checked malfunction after dealing with 2nd+ index in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, onclick

So i got this working with the first value x to be pushed and spliced but after it only pushes or doesn't do anything

```
for(x in aL.results){$('#tblListings').append(
            '<tr>'
                +'<td> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="updateListings[]" value='+x+' onclick="doSomething(this)">
</td>+'</tr>'
        );}
```

```js
function doSomething(cb) {
    if ($(cb).is(":checked")) {
        uLIndex.push(cb.value);
        alert(uLIndex);
    } else {
        uLIndex.splice(cb.value, 1);
        alert(uLIndex);
    }       
}
```

Comment: `cb.value` is not an index in the array, it's a string ("`+x+`"). See [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: Tested onchange event still same result, checking checkbox 2 and unchecking and re checking rsult is 1,1

Comment: Please re-read my comment, and also the documentation I've linked.

Comment: cb.value is a string representation of the index of the listing

Comment: ??? `"+x+"` can't be converted to an integer, can it?

Comment: @Teemu it can... if that part is replaced with a number by whatever backend is in use

Comment: the portion of the code is that its in <script> append, i just figured it was no t important

Comment: got to admit i like the responces of stack overflow, been just googling my problem.

Comment: @KevinB Doesn't look to be replaced in the example though. I could imagine there being more these checkboxes, it doesn't make much sense to hardcode indices to the values of the inputs. Most likely user won't check and re-check them in a specific order.

Comment: ok i hope this makes more sense even though i got a good answer as a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is because you're providing the string value of the checkbox to `slice()`. Instead you need to provide the numerical index of the item to remove in the array. You can use `indexOf()` to retrieve that:

```js
var uLIndex = [];

function doSomething(cb) {
    if ($(cb).is(":checked")) {
        uLIndex.push(cb.value);
        console.log(uLIndex);
    } else {
        uLIndex.splice(uLIndex.indexOf(cb.value), 1); // note the change here
        console.log(uLIndex);
    }       
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="updateListings[]" value="1" onclick="doSomething(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="updateListings[]" value="2" onclick="doSomething(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="updateListings[]" value="3" onclick="doSomething(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="updateListings[]" value="4" onclick="doSomething(this)">
```

Also note that it's considered better practice to use unobtrusive event handlers over the now outdated `on*` event attributes. You can also simplify the code to build the array on each click using jQuery's `map()` method, instead of having to track additions/removals manually. Try this:

```js
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
  var uLIndex = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get();
  console.log(uLIndex);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="updateListings[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="updateListings[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="updateListings[]" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" name="updateListings[]" value="4">
```

As with most things that involve jQuery, this version has the advantage of using much simpler logic but being slightly slower (although we're talking milliseconds only). If you need a higher level of performance I'd argue that you probably shouldn't use jQuery at all.

Comment: Although in your second solution, i am concerned is there is 2 different checkbox arrays for 2 different functions, how can java-script be differentiated...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - it still builds the same single array. The logic of both examples has the same result.

Comment: I am just wondering if there is 2 different sets of check boxes, one for listings and the other lets say to edit only title, or to edit title and descriptions or even any possibilities. so it works with set listings, but how can it see different when looking at set properties

Comment: Ah I see - in that case you would need to restrict the `map()` function to only select those checkboxes you require. I'd suggest starting a new question with your full HTML sample.

Comment: I may, but for now I am satisfied with your solution, the only issue is the second solution
$('input:checkbox').change(function() { doesnt seem to catch any changes

Comment: ok started a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41470887/no-return-oninputcheckbox-changefunction

Comment: the second solution seams to only work on pure html input but not appended, How could i use it.

Comment: For appended content you need to use a delegated event handler: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132341/discussion-between-andrei-pak-and-rory-mccrossan).

Comment: I figured it out, original data was coded in ajax, so i my mistake was makign the event handler outside the scope