# No return on$('input:checkbox').change(function() {?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, input

I am testing a second solution that has been provided to me here, for checking and recording each check box that has been checked. First solution works like a charm but the second more efficient solution does not even run.

```
for (x in aL.results) {
  aLIds.push(aL.results[x].listing_id);
  aLTitles.push(aL.results[x].title);
  aLQuantities.push(aL.results[x].quantity);
  aLDescs.push(aL.results[x].description);
  aLTaxPaths.push(aL.results[x].Tax_path);
  aLTaxIds.push(aL.results[x].Tax_id);
  aLTags.push(aL.results[x].tags);
  aLUrls.push(aL.results[x].url);
  aLPrices.push(aL.results[x].price);
  aLViews.push(aL.results[x].views);
  aLHearts.push(aL.results[x].num_favorers);

  $('#tblListings').append(
    '<tr>' + '<td><input type="checkbox" name="updateListings[]" value=' + x + ' ></td>' + '<td>' + aLQuantities[x] + '</td>' + '<td>' + aLTitles[x] + '</td>' + '<td>' + aLPrices[x] + '</td>' + '<td>' + aLViews[x] + '</td>' + '<td>' + aLHearts[x] + '</td>' + '</tr>'
  );
}

$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
    alert('ah');
    var uLIndex = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
    console.log(uLIndex);
});
```

Comment: You're missing the closing `}` for the `for` loop. Is the `.change()` call supposed to be inside the loop or after it's done?

Comment: After its done, and its just a snippet ill re edit the code

Comment: Which is the first solution and second solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically create element we can not bind event directly do something like this or **[live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)** function and this function is removed in 1.9 version so make sure what version of jquery you are using or many ways you can find out on [**jquery**](http://api.jquery.com/) official site

```
$('body').on("change","input:checkbox",function() {
    alert('ah');
  var uLIndex = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get();
  console.log(uLIndex);
});
```

**Updated**

Add a class to checkbox **check**

```
$('#tblListings').append(
    '<tr>' + '<td><input class="check" type="checkbox" name="updateListings[]" value=' + x + ' ></td>' + '<td>' + aLQuantities[x] + '</td>' + '<td>' + aLTitles[x] + '</td>' + '<td>' + aLPrices[x] + '</td>' + '<td>' + aLViews[x] + '</td>' + '<td>' + aLHearts[x] + '</td>' + '</tr>'
  );
```

And than bind event on all checkbox with class name **check** as below.

```
$('body').on("change",".check",function() {
    alert('ah');
  var uLIndex = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get();
  console.log(uLIndex);
});
```

Comment: `.live()` has been deprecated for years, and was removed in jQuery 1.9.

Comment: oh yes but we don't know na what jquery version he's using anyways thanx for you valuable suggestion i will update my answer accordingly

Comment: I am using 3.1.1 jquery

Comment: okk than **ON**  will work. please see my updated answer..